# What type of things should be tested in androidTest versus test

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am beginning to learn android development and I have a quick question about what should be tested where.

I have been looking through and studying the sample repository from [android/architecure-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/dagger-android) . I was wondering based on this type of project what gets tested from where?

For example what I gathered from the repository above:

androidTest

- Activity
- Navigation

unit

- Repository
- ViewModel

sharedTest

- Fragment
- Dao
- DataSource

Can someone shed some light on if this is correct or a common pattern? To me this seems rather odd. I would think that Fragment would be in androidTest and Dao and DataSource would be in unit test?

Answer (score 0):

- `androidTest` contains tests that required hardware to be involved. You can access the `Context` of your app. It is usually used for integration or UI automation test
- `test` contains tests that can run on local JVM. You can write tests for utils methods, funtional of classes

Refer: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing

- `sharedTest` contains tests of 2 types above. Why we have this? Basically, sometimes you should have test data that is used for both local and instrument tests. Instead of duplicate the data to `test` and `androidTest` folder, you can setup it here then write your tests.

Example: `FakeRepository` is declared in `sharedTest`. It can be used in `test`

Refer: https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-code-between-local-and-instrumentation-tests-c0b57ebd3200

Comment: Sorry I was trying to find a simple more concrete example. I have seen those articles above, but for a new developer I was hoping to get a simple defined example. Can you elaborate on if the example I gave above?